# Remmina to RDP to our Active Directory

Tags: windows, rdp, remmina

Can't RDP to our **Active Directory** after it renewed its certificate. I removed the `remmina.pref` file, but without luck. What Remmina asks for is accepting the cert and fingerprint first time it connects to a remote agent. I assume it then stores that info, although there is nothing that can be found in directory `~/.remmina` other than the `pref` file. I want to remove any old traces of the **Active Directory** cert, so it will ask me for the newest certificate and generate me a new fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in the `/home/user` directory `.freerdp`. It has a `known_hosts` file which stores the fingerprint. After deleting the entry of the host's IP, Remmina will regenerate a new cert when connecting.

Another solution can be to RDP with the host's `FQDN`.